# Why didn't Tina check the facts regarding Newt's engagement to Leta?

Tags: harry-potter, character-motivation, fantastic-beasts, the-crimes-of-grindelwald

Most Aurors are shown in the series to be incompetent buffoons. However, Tina was shown to be very competent and was an essential part of Newt's success in the first movie.

However, in *The Crimes of Grindelwald* we see Tina being cold and distant to Newt, completely believing in a tabloid article about his engagement to Leta Lestrange.

How is it possible that an educated and learned Auror did not bother checking her facts and just believed in a rag of a publication?

Comment: It is not because you are competent in your job that you don't struggle/make bad decisions in your love life. I found that subplot felt odd though, so here is my +1.

Comment: Because she's a chump

Comment: Newt loved Leta and Tina probably knew that from her legilimens sis. it was why the article hit her that hard. also ppl in luff can be pretty dramatic :/

Answer (score 6):

## Tina was upset and not thinking clearly.

When Tina saw the article in Spellbound about Newt, it upset her - her sister Queenie said she was “all in a tizzy” over it. After seeing it, it seems likely that Tina was sufficiently upset by what she thought had happened that she was overwhelmed and didn’t think to double-check if it was true.

> **QUEENIE** 
>   
> Oh well, you know, she found out about Jacob and I seeing each other and she didn’t like it, ’cause of the “law.” 
> *(miming quotation marks)* 
> Not allowed to date No-Majs, not allowed to marry them. Blah, blah, blah. Well, she was all in a tizzy anyway, ’cause of you.
>
> **NEWT** 
>   
> Me?
>
> **QUEENIE** 
> Yeah, you, Newt. It was in *Spellbound*. Here—I brought it for you—
>
> *She points her wand at her suitcase. A celebrity magazine zooms to her:* Spellbound: Celebrity Secrets and Spell Tips of the Stars! *On the cover, an idealized NEWT and an improbably beaming Niffler. <sub>BEAST TAMER NEWT TO WED!</sub>* 
> <sub><sup>*- Fantastic Beasts: The Crimes of Grindelwald (The Original Screenplay)*</sup></sub>

It’s clear she’s not thinking very logically, since her response is to hastily enter a relationship with another Auror.

> **QUEENIE** 
>   
> *(showing him)* 
>   
> “Newt Scamander with fiancée, Leta Lestrange; brother, Theseus; and unknown woman.”
>
> **NEWT**
>   
> No. Theseus is marrying Leta, not me.
>
> **QUEENIE** 
> Oh! Oh dear . . . well, see, Teen read that, and she started dating someone else. He’s an Auror. His name’s Achilles Tolliver. 
> <sub><sup>*- Fantastic Beasts: The Crimes of Grindelwald (The Original Screenplay)*</sup></sub>

Therefore, it seems likely that the reason Tina didn’t check to see if the information in the article was correct is because she was so upset that she wasn’t able to think about the situation rationally or logically.

## She also had reason to think it’d be true.

Additionally, Tina had reason to consider it plausible enough that Newt could be marrying Leta. She had known about Leta from before reading that article, because she asked Newt about her before Newt left for England.

> “*Weak smiles. A pause. TINA plucks up courage.*
>
> **TINA**
>   
> Does Leta Lestrange like to read?
>
> **NEWT**
>   
> Who?
>
> **TINA**
>   
> The girl whose picture you carry—
>
> **NEWT**
>   
> I don’t really know what Leta likes these days because people change.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them: The Original Screenplay*</sup></sub>

Presumably her sister Queenie had told her who Leta was, and about her past relationship with Newt, because Queenie had read Newt’s mind and learned his entire history with Leta.

> “*ANGLE ON a photograph inside NEWT’S shed, which shows a beautiful girl – the girl smiles suggestively. QUEENIE stares at the photo.*
>
> **QUEENIE**
>   
> Hey, Newt. Who is she?
>
> **NEWT**
>   
> Ah . . . that’s no one.
>
> **QUEENIE**
>   
> *(reading his mind)*
>   
> Leta Lestrange? I’ve heard of that family. Aren’t they kinda – you know?
>
> **NEWT**
>   
> Please don’t read my mind.
>
> *A beat as QUEENIE drinks the whole story out of NEWT’S head. She looks both intrigued and saddened. NEWT continues to work, trying hard to pretend QUEENIE isn’t reading his mind.*” 
> <sub><sup>*- Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them: The Original Screenplay*</sup></sub>

Queenie saw in Newt’s mind that he and Leta had been very close for years, and it’s likely she told Tina that as well.

> “**QUEENIE**
>   
> I know, I’m sorry, I can’t help it. People are easiest to read when they’re hurting.
>
> **NEWT**
>   
> I’m not hurting. Anyway, it was a long time ago.
>
> **QUEENIE**
>   
> That was a real close friendship you had at school.
>
> **NEWT**
>   
> *(attempting to be dismissive)*
>   
> Yes, well, neither of us really fitted in at school, so we—
>
> **QUEENIE**
>   
> —became real close. For years.
>
> *In the background we see TINA, who has noticed that NEWT and QUEENIE are talking.*” 
> <sub><sup>*- Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them: The Original Screenplay*</sup></sub>

Though it wasn’t actually true that Newt was marrying Leta, from what Tina knew about their history together, it would have seemed plausible enough for her to believe (especially considering she was upset at the news) without stopping to question it. Tina  hadn’t known Newt for *that* long, and they weren’t officially in a relationship, so it’s possible enough that Newt could have decided to marry Leta, who he’s known for years, instead of having a relationship with Tina.

Comment: Also, their relationship was more promissary than actual. As far as I'm aware they'd communicated via some letters but that's about it.

Comment: Thank you so much, whoever helped me fix this! :)